# import variables and its values from file

Tags: vb.net

i am working on a project to help me with my website 
but i am stuck on this step
simply i want to save this file as variables and values in vb.net
the file i am talking about looks like

```
"SIM" = "Micro-SIM"
"Weight" = "168 g (5.93 oz)"
"Announced" = "2013 =  September"
"Status" = "Available. Released 2013 =  September"
"Dimensions" = "151.2 x 79.2 x 8.3 mm (5.95 x 3.12 x 0.33 in)"
"Weight" = "168 g (5.93 oz)"
```

so the variable would be SIM and it's value would be Micro-SIM
i can also make the file in xls
thanks

Comment: Look into serialization...and please use only the applicable tags

Comment: There are two steps to this... Reading the file in a stream, and declaring new variables using reflection. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i already read the file
        Using file As StreamReader = New StreamReader("laptops.txt")
but i don't know other part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON files.
If you create a class which represent your data

```
Public Class Data
    Public Property SIM As String
End Class
```

You will be able to serialize

```
Dim data As New Data With { .SIM = "Micro-SIM" }
Dim stringData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
File.WriteAllText("laptop.json", stringData);
```

And deserialize it

```
Dim data As Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjec(Of Data)(File.ReadAllText("laptop.json"));
```

Then read and use values

```
Dim data As Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObjec(Of Data)(File.ReadAllText("laptop.json"))

textBoxSIM.Text = data.SIM ' Will show "Micro-SIM" in textbox
```

Or save values

```
Dim data As New Data()
data.SIM = textBoxSIM.Text
File.WriteAllText("laptop.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
```

Comment: thank you very mach but that's not what i meant 
i want to save the values in the json file as a variable and its value so when i type
Textbox1.text = SIM
it print the variable value which is in the json file (Micro-SIM)

Comment: After deserialization you can get all values from instance of your `Data` type. `textbox.Text = data.SIM`